# Go To Meeting equal for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have been looking for an open source equiv to "Go to meeting" for Ubuntu and have been unable to find anything. Is there anything you know of that has promise... and it would be helpful if the program allowed me to take control of a remote screen with permission of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want screen sharing, the simplest for the other user is http://www.uvnc.com/addons/singleclick.html It is VNC but packaged so the other user only needs to run a single executable. You have to do a bit more work, and may need to open a port on your firewall, unless you use a server relay.